# How to show flash notifications after page redirect

Tags: meteor

Given the following code:

```js
Posts.update(currentPostId, {$set: postProperties}, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        // display the error to the user
        alert(error.reason);
    } else {
        Router.go('postPage', {_id: currentPostId});
    }
});
```

How does one take the following code and add showing a flash message telling the user that the item has been updated on top of being directed to the new message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the various [flash message packages](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=flash)?

[naxio:flash](https://atmospherejs.com/naxio/flash) in particular supports `iron:router`.

Comment: Didn't realize it could be that easy with Meteor. That works, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome; Meteor is designed to be easy. If the package works for you, kindly [star it on Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/naxio/flash)!